# Why views not showing in one of the jetpack compose screen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add a simple row with two texts in one of the screens in JetpackCompose but I don't know why views are not showing.

**Note: Other screens are showing correctly but when I replace the below codes with that screen, I have the same issue**

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = "test".convertToPersianDigits(),
                    fontFamily = shabnamFontFamily,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(

                    text = "Test1",
                    fontFamily = shabnamFontFamily,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
                )
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

**If I add a padding modifier to `Box` or `Column`, Or change the `Text` `FontSize`, I can see a part of the text:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` draws behind the system bars like the status bar or navigation bar.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowCompat#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(android.view.Window,boolean))

> If set to false, the framework will not fit the content view to the insets and will just pass through the WindowInsetsCompat to the content view.

If you want your composable to draw behind the system components, you must pass false to the above method.

Now, if you want some content to not draw behind system bars, you can use different system padding modifiers available in compose.

```kotlin
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().statusBarsPadding()) {
       ...
}
```

The **[statusBarsPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).statusBarsPadding())** will prevent the drawing behind the status bar. Similar padding is available for the navigation bar, safe content drawing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

you have to apply to the root container the [**`statusBarsPadding`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).statusBarsPadding()) modifier to add padding to accommodate the system bars insets.

Something like:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .statusBarsPadding()
){
    //content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented this code in the `MainActivity` and it's fixed. Is it the correct solution?

```
   WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```